# How do you create a bar at the bottom of the browser that is persistent?

Tags: css, footer, sticky-footer

What HTML/CSS is used to create a bar that fills the bottom of the browser and remains in place when the user scrolls?  See [envato.com](http://www.envato.com) for an idea of what I'm talking about.

Comment: Search before asking.  Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294/how-do-you-get-the-footer-to-stay-at-the-bottom-of-a-web-page

Comment: I did search and maybe I'm just 'search challenged' but I only found things for making sure the footer stayed at the bottom when the page didn't fill the whole screen.  I'll be more diligent next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used this method before and it seems to work just fine.

http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -142px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
}
.footer, .push {
    height: 142px; /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
}
```

Comment: Awesome!  Worked like a charm!